# How to add shortcuts to navigation bar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

I'm looking for adding *shortcuts* to the navigation bar in Windows 10.
I mean by **shortcuts** the .lnk files that can be a shortcut to a file or folder.

---

### Alternatives that didn't work for me

- *Quick Access* section of Windows 10 file explorer ([shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMMZI.png)).

  Why? Because ...

  - The shortcut and original (referred to) folder can't have different names. [*However it's possible to pin a folder, the only problem is that I can only rename the shortcut by renaming the original folder.*]
  - I can't add files' shortcuts. [*It's not possible to pin a file to Quick Sections ([shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkru5.png)).*]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you should just be able to right-drag a file or folder to the navigation menu.

Comment: It's not possible to pin a file to _Quick Sections_ ([shot](http://i.imgur.com/2nPbOO4.png)). However it's possible to pin a folder, the only problem is that I can only rename the shortcut by renaming the original folder (_shortcut and original folder can't have different names_).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create shortcuts of the .exe files

1) Search the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\**Start Menu\Programs**

2) Paste the shortcuts there or in a specific folder.

3) Then go to the Start or Win logo and drag them to the navigation section.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the kines  next to the favorites bar,  this opens the sub menu, then click on the desired shortcut and drag normally to favorites bar folder.